# XAML - Binding Group Header In Group Header Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Not trying to post a duplicate of this thread:
[WPF - Binding to current item from within group header style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147702/wpf-binding-to-current-item-from-within-group-header-style)

I got the binding working.  I'm stil unclear why it works.    This part of the XAML sets up the group item and binds the Texbox to the text.  What I don't understand is the Binding to the 'Name' property.  What is 'Name' a property of? The group header?  Until I found the linked thread I was trying to bind to a property on the items in the data grid.

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
      <Expander IsExpanded="True"
                Background="#FF112255"
                BorderBrush="#FF002255"
                Foreground="#FFEEEEEE"
                BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
         <Expander.Header>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                         Text="SVC Node: "/>
                 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"/>
             </StackPanel>
           </Expander.Header>
         <Expander.Content>
        <ItemsPresenter />
       </Expander.Content>
      </Expander>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` refers to the property of the [System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) object that gets created by WPF and being set as the `DataContext` of a `GroupItem`.

This property returns the value of the property that you group the source collection by. So if you for example group a source collection of `Person` objects by a property called `Sex`, the `Name` property of the `CollectionViewGroup` would return something like "Male" or "Female". This `Name` property is not a property of your custom model class.

The `CollectionViewGroup` class also has a an `Items` property that returns the collection of objects, for example all `Person` objects where the `Sex` property returns "Male", that belongs to the specific group.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thank you.  That is the conclusion I came to.  The Microsoft example I linked to also includes a second text box bound to a property of the items in the Datagrid.  That's what confused me the first time I did this.

Answer (score 0):

if your model contains the Name property and also GroupItem's DataContext contains  same model object then Name property visible and able to access inside the control template. So that name property binding works in TextBlock.

Updated:
 based on my analysis , corresponding grouped property has assigned internally into group item's Name property, SO that it automatically derived to its childs,
[image]

Comment: that's what Im confused about.  My model, well my collection of objects, the objects in the collection don't have a Name property and it still works.  This example provided by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx  there is not a Name property in the Task class, but it works. I thought the binding was to a property of one of the objects in the collection, evidently it's not.